# What is a easy way to view texi files?

Tags: command-line, documentation, conversion

I am reading some files for a library I plan on using and the files are of extension '.texi' and although I can open the files in gedit, all the syntax and markups make it difficult to read. Also, I cant use the embedded links within the document. Is there an go-to program for reading .texi files? I am using Ubuntu 13.10 btw. Thx!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install texi2html to convert Texinfo files to HTML:

```
sudo apt-get install texi2html
```

Man page of texi2html:

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>    texi2html [options] file
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> ```
>    Texi2html  converts  the  given Texinfo file to a set of HTML files. It
>    tries to handle most of the  Texinfo  commands.  It  creates  hypertext
>    links for cross-references, footnotes...
>
>    Texi2html  may furthermore use latex2html to generate HTML (code and/or
>    images) for @math and @iftex tags (see the --l2h option).
>
>    Texi2html creates several files depending on the contents of  the  Tex‐
>    info file and on the chosen options (see FILES).
>
>    The  HTML  files created by texi2html are in general closer to TeX than
>    to Info. Using init files (see the --init-file option), other styles or
>    output formats may be selected.
> ```
>
> [...]

Comment: I think `texinfo` was discontinued in 2011 and that `makeinfo --html` is preferred: http://askubuntu.com/a/644387/52975

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚威视, good to know, thanks and +1 for your answer.

Comment: @CiroSantilliПутлерКапут六四事 I think you mean that `texi2html` was discontinued, not `texinfo`.

Comment: @AJM as I was saying, I think `texi2html` was discontinued in 2011 and that `makeinfo --html` is preferred ;-)

Answer (score 12):

**`makeinfo` from the `texinfo` package**

```
sudo apt install texinfo
makeinfo --html --no-split -o a.html a.texi
firefox a.html
```

You can also convert to many other formats if you prefer:

- `makeinfo a.texi`.

  Generates an `a.info` file which can be opened with:

  ```
  info -f a.info
  ```

  This is the most "native" local GNU documentation format.
- `makeinfo --pdf a.info`

  Requires LaTeX.

`texi2html` appears to have been deprecated in 2011: http://www.nongnu.org/texi2html/

> development of Texi2HTML and of the Texi2HTML based makeinfo implementation stopped in 2011.

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04.

**Binutils docs**

Here is how you can build the Binutils docs like GDB and GAS, which are in texinfo format, to a single HTML page nirvana: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477303/how-to-build-the-gdb-documentation-from-source/477309#477309

Answer (score 2):

You can use `texiinfo` :

Texinfo uses a single source file to produce output in a number of formats, both online and printed (dvi, html, info, pdf, xml, etc.). This means that instead of writing different documents for online information and another for a printed manual, you need write only one document. And when the work is revised, you need revise only that one document. The Texinfo system is well-integrated with GNU Emacs.

You can downlod it from [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/texinfo/), eg:

```
cd
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/texinfo/texinfo-6.0.tar.xz
tar xf texinfo-6.0.tar.xz
```

Compile and install:

```
cd texiinfo-6.0
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

After installation use `man texiinfo` and learn how to convert it .

More info [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/)